# What is correct configuration of input parameters for calculating RSI (and ROC)

Tags: javascript, node.js, technical-indicator, rsi

I have tried to use [Technical Indicators library](https://github.com/anandanand84/technicalindicators) to calculate `RSI` (and `ROC`) for candlestick's closing prices, but when I compare results from [Binance](https://www.binance.com/en), I am not getting quite accurate results:

I fetch data using this [Binance API](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#kline-candlestick-data):

This is example of usage for [RSI](https://runkit.com/anandaravindan/rsi) and [ROC](https://runkit.com/anandaravindan/roc) indicators:

If I do this:

```
let inputData = {
        values: data, // 15 candlesticks, 1m candlestick data, values[0] is oldest closing price
        period: 14,
      };
```

and I do calculation:

```
const results_rsi = RSI.calculate(inputData);
```

I get single element array, with quite **inaccurate** result in compare to (realtime) data on Binance.

If I do this:

```
let inputData = {
        values: data, // 100 candlesticks, 1m candlestick data, values[0] is oldest closing price
        period: 14,
      };

 const results_rsi = RSI.calculate(inputData);
```

I get a result with a bunch of elements, and if I compare `result_rsi`'s **last** element with Binance `RSI 14 (1m)` I get actually very **accurate** result. Also, I have read in one of the [git issues](https://github.com/anandanand84/technicalindicators/issues/249) that providing more historical data is better.

Now, so far so good... Or at least that is what I thought :) However, both RSI and ROC results were very accurate.

The thing is, when I applied same logic, but with different parameters, say like this:

```
let inputData = {
        values: data, // 100(or even 200 and 500) candlesticks, 1h candlestick data, values[0] is oldest closing price
        period: 30,
      };

       const results_rsi = RSI.calculate(inputData);
      const results_roc = ROC.calculate(inputData);
```

and I check last element of `results_rsi` and `results_roc` (which I consider that are actual results, but maybe not?), I am still getting quite good results for `RSI`, but for `ROC` I am getting very wrong results. It makes me think if I even use this library correctly, and I am not quite sure if even `RSI` results are correct, cause I didn't try it with many different parameters / data.

So, the questions :

(from docs):

```
var data = 
[11045.27,11167.32,11008.61,11151.83,10926.77,10868.12,10520.32,10380.43,10785.14,10748.26,10896.91,10782.95,10620.16,10625.83,10510.95,10444.37,10068.01,10193.39,10066.57,10043.75];

var period = 12;
        
var expectResult = [-3.85,-4.85,-4.52,-6.34,-7.86,-6.21,-4.31,-3.24];
    
ROC.calculate({period : period, values : data});
```

1. What is the actual result of ROC here? Cause the array is returned.
2. How input values should be sorted? (what should be the `values[0]`)?
3. Where am I wrong? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What is sufficient Data-depth for "Accuracy" ?
<sub>*( better: When do we get equal outputs on screen ? )*</sub>

RSI is one of several indicators that include an element of prior data. As such a 14 day RSI based on 15 days or 50 days of underlying data will be significantly different to a 14 day RSI based on 500 days of data.

So, unless all TimeSeries' "observers" compute RSI from (a) the exactly the same TimeSeries and (b) using the very same "length" ( for depth-of-prior DATA dependent underlying computing, here starting with a plain SMA for the very first "observed" period-length bars ) and (c) using the very same numerical properties of computing methods ( having almost all platforms using the same 64-bit IEEE-754 numerical processing, this need not cause problems, using hybrid FPGA/GPGPU/SoC/ASIC algos yet may introduce this class of further incoherencies (causing new breed of differences in results) ),
so,
there is the highest chance to meet both (a) & (b) & (c) if and only if we all start from the very "beginning" of the DATA in the TimeSeries-history ( easy if we all use the same source of data, not so easy, if some use time-zone uncorrected, different history-depths from different (T)OHLC(V)-data sources ) and using the same numerical processing methods.

Some technical-indicators are less susceptible to depth-of-observation, some more ( if this is a core problem ( for sake of shaving latency off / increasing performance / maintaining Quant-models' reproducibility & repeatability of results ),
 try to set your "Accuracy" threshold and test all technical-indicators' dependence on the depth-of-prior DATA ( so as the convergence starts to meet your "Accuracy" threshold, making no sense to extend the depth further, if results started to converge and remain stable irrespective of any further extended depth-of-prior DATA re-processing )

In cases, where you happen to reach such "short enough" depth-of-prior DATA, you need not re-process a single bar deeper into past. Not so in all other cases, where DATA-depth dependence cannot be avoided. Pity, there we all need to take the same depth (often the maximum one, see above), if we want to get the same result(s).

Comment: `try to set your "Accuracy" threshold and test all technical-indicators' dependence on the depth-of-prior DATA` Yes, I didn't try this in detail but I kinda tried it. For example for ROC, I used 100/200/500/750 candlestick data, I still don't get not even near accurate results in compare to Binance (I am still thinking that maybe I use library a bit wrong or something). But I will certainly run more tests. Thanks!

Comment: And when I say 100/200/500/750 candlestick data, I fetch say 1h candlesticks, but I still use fixed ‘period’ parameter.

Comment: FYI: the number of candles is cardinal ( not the timeframe - be it H1, M5, M1 or even synth-vM3 or likes ). Some deeply convoluted Indicator-on-Indicator(s) must run on 100.000 ultra-fast ( besides several other, trading-engine optimised Indicators & algo-trading strategies, all that plus processing thousands of ToB / DoM / XTO events each milisecond ). So small number of thousands bars is indeed nothing special to mention here.

Comment: Gosh, it seems I was looking at a wrong candlestick. I was looking at latest candlestick, for example the one that starts at 22:46:00. Rather than one that ends at 22:45:59. Certainly number of candles affect on final precision, but even with few hundreds of candles I got very precise results for everything(same as on Binance). However...Thanks a lot for detailed explanation, at least it made me to look better to find an error, as well as to understand how and why differences may occur.