# ta-lib ATR method number of arguments error

Tags: python-3.x, trading, ta-lib, backtrader

i am re-using a code which calculates trailing stop of a trade strategy

```
def calculate_trailing_stop():
    xATR = talib.ATR(list(src), atrperiod)
```

here atrperiod is 10 and src is an array of last 10 samples.
when I run this program I got following error indicating that at least 3 arguments are required:

```
result = func(*_args, **_kwds)
File "talib/_func.pxi", line 495, in talib._ta_lib.ATR
TypeError: ATR() takes at least 3 positional arguments (2 given)
```

Can anyone tell what the third argument should be? i am using python 3.8.1

Comment: Reading this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71142257/what-is-correct-configuration-of-input-parameters-for-calculating-rsi-and-roc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71142257/what-is-correct-configuration-of-input-parameters-for-calculating-rsi-and-roc)
solved the problem